# longtable without head row

Tags: spacing, longtable

`longtable` without the head row starts not from the top of the page, but has offset. Is it a bug or a feature? How can I fix it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage[paper=a5paper,left=10mm,right=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=20mm,
showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable}

\newcounter{iii}
\setcounter{iii}{1}
\newcommand{\myrow}{\hline\theiii\stepcounter{iii}\\}

\begin{document}
\LTpre=0pt
\raggedbottom
\fontsize{30}{60}\selectfont
\begin{longtable}{|l|}

    \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow
    \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow
    \myrow \myrow \myrow

\end{longtable}

\newpage
\begin{longtable}{|l|}
\hline numbers\\
\endhead
    \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow
    \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow
    \myrow \myrow \myrow
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compare 3 upper and 3 lower pages]

Comment: Maybe the question should be reversed: Is it *ever* proper to use a `longtable` environment *without* providing `\endfirsthead`, `\endhead`, `\endfoot`, and `\endlastfoot` directives? Put differently, what is supposed to be achieved by creating a table with proper header (and footer) information?

Comment: @Mico What package should I use to get the multipage table _without_ running headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length `\topskip` is used to move the baseline down from the top of the text area so that the first line of text fits.  Evidently longtable starts under the current baseline.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage[paper=a5paper,left=10mm,right=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=20mm,
showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable}

\newcounter{iii}
\setcounter{iii}{1}
\newcommand{\myrow}{\hline\theiii\stepcounter{iii}\\}


\begin{document}
\bgroup
\topskip=0pt
\LTpre=0pt
\raggedbottom
\fontsize{30}{60}\selectfont
\begin{longtable}{|l|}
    \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow
    \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow \myrow
    \myrow \myrow \myrow
\end{longtable}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: And what is the default value of `\topskip`?

Comment: About 10pt.  Don't worry, it will automatically be restored at \egroup.