# Vertical space between longtable and top of the page

Tags: spacing, longtable

With the environment `longtable` we make a table crossing the page boundary.
If a table has a head (`\endhead` command), `longtable` works perfectly: the baseline of the first line in a usual text page and the baseline of the first line of text in the table are coinside.

[image: longtable with head]

But, if a table doesn't have a head, the baseline of the first line of text in the table is lower then the baseline of the first line in a usual text page.

[image: longtable without head]

How to reduce the space between top of a page and a table without head?

Is it possible to slightly modify the `longtable` package so that all tables in a document would be fixed?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lhead{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{longtable}{|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}|}
 \hline
  Header & Header \\
 %\endhead %% Uncomment this line for table with head
 \hline
  \lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2] \\
 \hline
  \lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2] \\
 \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366603/longtable-without-head-row/366701?s=1|40.2543#366701

Comment: @John, thank you for pointing that.
Вut setting `\topskip` to 0pt doesn't solve the problem.
Actually, we should reduce `\topskip` by some amount of space.  
In my case, this amount is height of vertical rule, which presents part of left border of the first cell.  
It depends on the content of the first lines of top table cells. In my case it is always 8.4pt, because font doesn't change and lines contain only letters, and start with capital letters.  
This `\topskip` later will be reduced by 0.4pt, the thickness of top border.  
I think, it can be somehow implemented in `longtable.sty`.

Comment: it's not really that it doesn't have a head, more that the first thing is an `\hline` and so that aligns on the first baseline. Probably the easiest thing is to always have a head, if you put the hline and the first row in `\endfirsthead` then it should work I think. You don't need to have a head on the later pages.

Comment: You're right, @David. Space before table is correct without `\hline`. But  `\endfirsthead` without `\endhead` doesn't solve problem.

Comment: @John, in my case the simpliest way is to put `\topskip=1.6pt`. But it is too simple. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\firsthline` from the array package instead of `\hline`:

```
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{geometry,tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\geometry{top=2cm}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
 \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[red] ([yshift=-2cm-\topskip]current page.north west) -- ++(\textwidth,0);}

\begin{document}
some text
\newpage 
\begin{longtable}{l}
\hline
abc
\end{longtable}
\newpage
\begin{longtable}{l}
\firsthline
abc
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It works only for the second page of a table, but doesn't for the third.

Comment: If this means that you want to repeat the header line on following pages than setting topskip locally is probably your best option beside patching longtable. An alternative is to check for the first line on a page and draw the header line with tikz instead of using \endhead (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384925/2388 for a first line check).

Answer (score 0):

The next patch to `longtable` works for me, assuming that if `\hline` is present in table, it is present after all `\\`.

```
%
% Adjustment of longtable environment
%
\makeatletter
\newskip\ax@LT@topskip
\newif\ifax@LT@hline
% Save original definitions
\let\ax@LT@longtable=\longtable
\let\ax@LT@endlongtable=\endlongtable
\let\ax@LT@output=\LT@output
\let\ax@LT@hline=\LT@hline
% Remember, there was \hline
\def\LT@hline{%
 \noalign{\global\ax@LT@hlinetrue}%
 \ax@LT@hline
}
% Forget about \hline, store initial value of \topskip
\def\longtable{%
 \global\ax@LT@hlinefalse
 \ax@LT@topskip=\topskip
 \ax@LT@longtable
}
% Adjust \topskip, if there was \hline and wasn't \endhead
\def\LT@output{%
 \ifax@LT@hline\ifvoid\LT@head
  \global\topskip=\ax@LT@topskip
  \global\advance\topskip by -\ht\@arstrutbox
 \fi\fi
 \ax@LT@output
}
% Restore \topskip
\def\endlongtable{%
 \ax@LT@endlongtable
 \global\topskip=\ax@LT@topskip
}
\makeatother
```